# Elixir converting a list of tuples to a Map

Tags: elixir

I have a list of tuples for request headers like

```
req_headers: [
{"accept", "application/json"},
{"accept-encoding", "gzip"},
{"date", "Thu, 03 Jun 2021 13:58:49 GMT"}
]
```

I am attempting to covert this to a pure Map which would look like:

```
%{"accept" => "application/json", "accept-encoding" => "gzip", "date" => "Thu, 03 Jun 2021 13:58:49 GMT"}
```

So far I've tried a number of combinations using Enum.map and Enum.each to convert each entry to a pair and add them to a Map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Map.new/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/1) is your friend.

```elixir
Map.new [
  {"accept", "application/json"},
  {"accept-encoding", "gzip"},
  {"date", "Thu, 03 Jun 2021 13:58:49 GMT"}
]

#⇒ %{
#   "accept" => "application/json",
#   "accept-encoding" => "gzip",
#   "date" => "Thu, 03 Jun 2021 13:58:49 GMT"
# }
```